# unknown user name or bad password when I tried to connect to another server

Tags: asp.net, security

I need to read the file of another server via vb.net application. For this case I tried to read destination file by FileSream.

The destination file in the another server is (\dstServer\sheardFolder\dstFilename). for destination parent path I type \dstServer\sharedFolder\Filename and this string is included in the FileSream Class. When I run this application I get the error of asp.net with this subject (Login failure: unknown user name or bad password)...!!!

I set the following permissions on the parent folder at the destination Server

1- users have a full permission

2- everyone have a full permission

3- asp.net have a full permission

Note: I searched in the internet and noticed that in the first step I should connect to the destination Server and my users should be authenticated by the destination Server.

After that I used .Net security classes and advapi32.dll , Kernel32.dll also impersonateValidUser.
I set the destination Server username and destination Server password and destination Server name or IP in the impersonateValidUser function but when I run the applciation, I get the response (failed) which means that connect to the destination Server is failed.

This application that is used to connect the users with destination server was in the following microsoft sample code:    http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842789

Please give me tips.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What webserver are you running on? (IIS or the development server that ships wiht visual studio ?) Which version?